# Google Analytics Embed API - set language

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using [Google Analytics Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) in one of my projects and I haven't figured out if it is possible to change language of the rendered charts. Default one is english. Autentication is done on a backend side and I use google service account for gathering the data (the exact same scenario as shown [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/))

I assume it should be possible since Google Analytics are available in different languages, but I was not able to find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Analytics reporting API returns data in English only there is no way to change the language it is returned in.

The Embeded API access the Google Analytics reporting API.  If you want to change the language you will have to pre-process all of the data returned from the API yourself and change the language and then display it in the Embeded graphics API .

Comment: since this is for a year ago, is there any update on this, still not implemented?

Comment: Personally I don't think the team will ever bother translating the data returned by Google analytics apis.   So no this is still not implemented.

Comment: I don't get it, they have already implemented it inside analytics dashboard, whatever they do to translate data over there, they can wire it to the API

Comment: The data in the backend is in English.  If the website is translating it that's up to it.   The team behind the website and the team behind the API are two different teams.   You could create a feature request however I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't one for that already.

Comment: Bigger problem: if you use both Google Analytics API and Google Charts API in the same page, and you load the Charts API in a different language (because for that they did think about the existence of other languages), you'll get an error. Which, by the way, says "can't load different versions of the Google Charts API", so you'll waste days trying to figure out why you are seemingly loading different versions. So not only you can't have the data in other languages, you also can't have unrelated graphs with the proper decimal separators just because you have Analytics Embed in the same page.